# Python removing words en characters from a text file

Tags: python

file1.txt

```
neighbors:
  - { neighbor: 192.168.3.1,remote-as: 200,group: Google } 
  - { neighbor: 192.168.4.1,remote-as: 300,group: FOX }
  - { neighbor: 192.168.15.1,remote-as: 400,group: TAX }
  - { neighbor: 192.168.16.1,remote-as: 500,group: TSL }
  - { neighbor: 192.168.5.1,remote-as: 400,group: TAM }
```

i want ot make an file1.txt ( without the first line en (-{},:,)

```
neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote-as 200
neighbor 192.168.4.1 remote-as 300
neighbor 192.168.15.1 remote-as 400
neighbor 192.168.16.1 remote-as 500
neighbor 192.168.5.1 remote-as 400
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code of what you have tried

Comment: Try to do it using online docs and then if you run into error, Post it.

Comment: I have tried many options!!! but it didn'n work

Comment: I was correct in my first guess, writing it now as it's not so easy if you don't recognise the file format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is in YAML format. Normally you would specify this with `.yml` extension rather than `.txt` but it doesn't affect the file contents. Rather than parse with something like regex, you can instead read in the YAML format and write back out in your desired output. See the [documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) for PyYAML for more details.

```
import yaml

with open('test.txt') as infile:
    data = yaml.load(infile)

with open('test_out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for neighbor in data['neighbors']:
        outfile.write('neighbor {} remote-as {}\n'.format(neighbor['neighbor'],
                                                          neighbor['remote-as']))
```

Note that dictionaries only started becoming ordered in python 3.6, and only guaranteed to be ordered in 3.7+, so for earlier versions of Python, it cannot be guaranteed that you will get the exact desired output.

You could mitigate this by specifying the sub-dictionary keys in the string you're writing out.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!!

Comment: This is the output! but i needed only neighbor en remote-as!!!                  
neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote 200 group Google
neighbor 192.168.4.1 remote 300 group FOX
neighbor 192.168.15.1 remote 400 group TAX
neighbor 192.168.16.1 remote 500 group TSL
neighbor 20.249.208.165 remote 200 group SAN
neighbor 80.249.208.165 remote 100 group SHAN
neighbor 192.168.5.1 remote 400 group TAM

Comment: @SurenA I have fixed it to drop the final key

Comment: Amezing!!!Thanks